# Push notification alert view action?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I have an iphone application in which i am doing the push notification as an alertview.When my application is in the background state the push notification is coming,and when i am clicking on it or unlocking the phone it is directly entering in to the app where i have left it in the forground state.I am adding an action in the alert with a click on view button it is going to another view controller.I Dnt want to enter the application  when i am clicking on the notification.I need to show the alertview and when clicking on the view button i need to do my action.Can anybody help me to achieve this.This is my code snippet `-

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //check application in forground or background
    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        //NSLog(@"FOreGround");
        //NSLog(@"and Showing %@",userInfo)
    }
    else
    {   
        NSDictionary *curDict= [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
        UIAlertView *connectionAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"app" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[curDict objectForKey:@"alert"]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"View" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
        [connectionAlert show];
        [connectionAlert release];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber =[[curDict objectForKey:@"badge"] intValue];   
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillEnterForeground");
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"View"]) 
    {   
        NSArray *mycontrollers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
        NSLog(@"%@",mycontrollers);
        [[mycontrollers objectAtIndex:0] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        mycontrollers = nil;  
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but could you be more precise? You don't want to enter the app when touching the notification? That is not possible at all...

Answer (score 0):

You show the UIAlertView to the user, When notification is received then the **didReceiveRemoteNotification:** function is called.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
        NSLog(@"userInfo :%@",userInfo);

        NSString* msg = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];

        if (self._VCObj.isViewLoaded && self._VCObj.view.window) {
                // viewController is visible don't show.
        }
            else { // viewController is not visible
                [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
            }
        }
    }
```

[See Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)